# Class with private construct instantiated outside class

Tags: java

I found this code online where the person is instantiating a class which has a private constructor outside the class. I am not able to understand how this works, cause from what I had read earlier, you use a private constructor in a class so that it cannot be instantiated outside the class.

```
public final class A extends B {
  private A(Something, Something)
  {
    //Something
  }

  public void someMethods()
  {
    //Something
  }
}

public final class B {
  private A a;
  public void someMethod()
  {
    final ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
                            new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));
    a = (A) objectInputStream.readObject();
    objectInputStream.close();

    a.someMethods();
  }
}
```

I just want to understand what exactly is going on here? I tried reading up on `ObjectInputStream` but could not get anything out of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the constructor is never called since the object is not being constructed but deserialized. Thus the access modifier has no effect here.

Serialization is basically the process of writing part of the content of the heap into some stream/file etc. Constructing an object will create a new object on the heap and call the constructor to initialize it. It then has a state which is retained during serialization. Hence there's no need for initializing that object again when it is deserialized. It's just like reading that part of the heap from a stream/file into memory again.

Besides that, keep in mind that there are ways to circumvent access modifiers by using reflection.

Comment: So does that mean that this particular object behaves like a static object? Meaning, there would be only one instance of it since it got mapped form the heap? Not sure if I am clear.

Comment: Well, there's always only one instance of an object since an object _is_ an instance of a class. If you mean if this would be something like a singleton (only one instance of a class), then the answer is no. You can serialize and deserialize multiple objects of the same class.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the code is instantiating an object via serialization and then casting that object to class A.  Nowhere in here is the class A constructor invoked.

Comment: +1 You don't need access to the constructor to perform deserialization.

Comment: In the OpenJDK it calls `Unsafe.allocateInstance(Class)` which allocates an instance of a class without calling a constructor. It needs to do this to restore the fields as it serialized them and a constructor can have side effects.

Comment: For reference, OP, this _appears_ to be something of a dirty hack.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I tried the `Unsafe` class but could not find a static method `allocateInstance(Class)` in it. It says the `Unsafe` is undocumented. When I checked the code, all the methods in there are deprecated.

Comment: have a look http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/Unsafe.java.html `/** Allocate an instance but do not run any constructor.
  Initializes the class if it has not yet been. */
       public native Object allocateInstance(Class cls)
           throws InstantiationException;`

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with Serialization and when you de-serialize, the Constructor is actually NOT called.